# Unknown attribute "android:padding"

Tags: android, android-layout

Since I'm not quite sure when, I'm getting a lint warning when viewing my layout file of `"Unknown attribute android:padding"`...

The layout file starts:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
    android:id="@+id/widget" >
```

I'm getting similar warnings for `android:layout_alignParentTop` etc in the following:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView_port"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Furthermore, I'm finding now that when an image is loaded into the `ImageView` that is the correct aspect ratio but not the right pixel size (smaller), the image is being shown in the `ImageView` at its actual (too small) size rather than being stretched out to fit the `ImageView` (like it used to do, and like I want it to do).

I'm not sure when these warnings started to appear.  And I'm confused because it appears that at least android:padding is still a valid attribute according to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:padding).

Other warnings I'm getting include for `android:tag`... which is also a pretty basic attribute and still "legal" according to the above docs.

Comment: try to clean and rebuild your project

Comment: @suvojit_007 makes no difference... I also did Invalidate Caches / Restart and still the warnings show... all layouts still seem to work OK, apart from the ImageView issue I mentioned (though not sure if that's related at all)

Comment: It's maybe been happening since I migrated to AndroidX (not sure): https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 0):

So, clean and rebuild did nothing, and Invalidate Caches / Restart also did nothing.

But the following worked:

- Close Android Studio
- Remove the content of folder `C:\Users\MyName\.AndroidStudio3.4\system\caches`
- Open Android Studio

That's it... not sure why "Invalidate Caches" wouldn't have achieved the same thing... maybe that is clear some other caches.

P.S. didn't solve the "image not being stretched to fit ImageView" but that must be a different issue.